# php set winning percentage from simple game

Tags: php

i had a very simple game, the game is choosing between BLACK and WHITE

here is the code :

===========================

```
        function acakangkahuruf($panjang) { 
$karakter= '01'; $string = ''; 
for ($i = 0; $i < $panjang; $i++) { $pos = rand(0, strlen($karakter)-1); 
$string .= $karakter{$pos}; } return $string; } 
$random=acakangkahuruf(1);
 if ($random==0) $katanya=1;

 if ($random==1) $katanya=2;


 if ($katanya==1) $katanya2=Black;
 if ($katanya==2) $katanya2=White;
 if ($jawab==1) $kataku2=Black;
 if ($jawab==2) $kataku2=White;

if ($jawab > $katanya){
$query = "INSERT INTO `game` (
`id` ,
`user` ,
`uang` ,
`pasang` ,
`jawab` ,
`untung`,
`duit`
)
VALUES (
'','$user','$duit','$jawab','$random','rugi', '$duit'
);";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$q = "update tb_users set money=money-'$duit' where username='$user'";
          mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

echo "
<center>
 <font size='400px' color='aqua' face='verdana'>$katanya2</font><br>
Maaf. Jawabannya adalah : $katanya2 <br>dan jawaban anda : $kataku2 . <br>Anda belum beruntung . </center><br><br>";

}
else if ($jawab < $katanya){
$query = "INSERT INTO `game` (
`id` ,
`user` ,
`uang` ,
`pasang` ,
`jawab` ,
`untung`,
`duit`
)
VALUES (
'','$user','$duit','$jawab','$random','rugi', '$duit'
);";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$q = "update tb_users set money=money-'$duit' where username='$user'";
          mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

echo "
<center>
 <font size='400px' color='aqua' face='verdana'>$katanya2</font><br>
Maaf. Jawabannya adalah : $katanya2 <br>dan jawaban anda : $kataku2 . <br>Anda belum beruntung . </center><br><br>";

}
else
{
$query = "INSERT INTO `game` (
`id` ,
`user` ,
`uang` ,
`pasang` ,
`jawab` ,
`untung`,
`duit`
)
VALUES (
'','$user','$duit','$jawab','$random','untung', '$duit'
);";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$menang=$config["menang"];
$untung3=$menang-100;
$untung2=$untung3*$duit;
$untung=$untung2/100;
$menangnya=$duit+$untung;
$q = "update tb_users set money=money+'$untung' where username='$user'";
          mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
echo "
<center>
 <font size='400px' color='aqua' face='verdana'>$random</font><br>
Mantap. Jawabannya adalah : $katanya2 <br>dan jawaban anda : $kataku2 . <br>Anda berhak mendapat Rp $menangnya . </center><br><br>";
```

==================================

the problem is, I donot understand how to create a winning chances percentage.

naturally the winning percentage for each BLACK or WHITE is 50% ,

now what I want is :

for what ever players pick ( either BLACK or WHITE) the winning chances for them is only 30%.

so the 70% chances automatically goes to the oposite of what they are choosing

eg :

you pick BLACK

now the game automatically recognize what you pick, and set your winning chances into 30%.

thank you very much for your help

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: If there are two choices, the chances are 50%, I'm guessing you want the percentage of times they were right or something? This sounds like homework...

Comment: thank you , I edited what I am asking for. I hope it's clear enough.
:)

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you're asking, but it sounds like you want:

```
if(mt_rand(1,10) <= 3) // 30% chance
    return 'BLACK';
else
    return 'WHITE';
```

Comment: thank you for your answer :) .. may I know where to put those code? Thank you :)